# maven checkstyle plugin and guava / google-collections dependency clash

Tags: maven, maven-3, guava, checkstyle

In our multiple module maven (3) project we are utilising the maven checkstyle plugin. It looks like that since we've shifted the guava dependency to our parent pom, we can't execute successfully the checkstyle:checkstyle goal anymore, because it fails with the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-
plugin:2.10:checkstyle (default-cli) on project init: Execution default-cli of goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:checkstyle failed: An API 
incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
checkstyle-plugin:2.10:checkstyle: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.of([Ljava/lang/Comparable;)Lcom/google
/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSet;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
```

The reason might be that the maven checkstyle plugin depends on the checkstyle framework, which depends on the google-collections framework (that is nowadays included in the google guava framework), i.e., that checkstyle calls a method that is not part of google collections in guava anymore.

Here is an excerpt of the parent pom that were are utilising:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ourcompany.ourproject</groupId>
<artifactId>ourproject</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>our project</name>

<modules>
    <module>init</module>

...

</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.14</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>2.10</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
    <maven-pmd-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-pmd-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.6</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <java.source.version>1.6</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>1.6</java.target.version>
    <google.guava.version>14.0.1</google.guava.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Internal Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://ourinternalmavenrepository/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

...

</repositories>

<build>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.source.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.source.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.source.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

...

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>deployment</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://ourinternalmavenrepository/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>deployment</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://ourinternalmavenrepository/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<profiles>

...

    <profile>
        <id>metrics</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- CHECKSTYLE -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>our_checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                        <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.source.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.ourcompany.ourproject</groupId>
                            <artifactId>init</artifactId>
                            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-pmd-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                        <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.source.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>our_checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <targetJdk>${java.source.version}</targetJdk>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-pmd-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <targetJdk>${java.source.version}</targetJdk>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<!-- <dependencyManagement> -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${google.guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

...

</dependencies>
<!-- </dependencyManagement> -->
```

I think that utilising the maven checkstyle plugin in a maven project is very common as well as utilising the guava framework. So I'm really wondering what we are doing wrong here ;)

Comment: Nothing wrong here, this happens sometimes =) Just add necessary dependency to `checkstyle` plugin.

Comment: strange, but it works. So thanks a lot @AndrewLogvinov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot @AndrewLogvinov. He prodivded the working solution in his comment to this question. One just needs to add the google-collections dependency to the dependencies of the maven-checkstyle-plugin:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```